# Cancel request for [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I want that at fist 30 minutes my application will using my GPS in the background so i do the following:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = nil;
            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            locationManager.distanceFilter =  kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
            locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
            [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

After 30 minutes i want that my application will run only in foreground...

How can i remove the thread which using my gps in background?

As i understood i need to add  [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] and [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
it works but in the app settings under privacy -> location services- > then there is 3 options: 1)never 2) While using the app 3)Always and even the app not running in the background  then the third option is selected still 3)Always I want that the setting will change to "While using the app"

Answer (score 0):

The authorisation process is separate to actually requesting location updates be delivered to your `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

Once you have been granted permission to use location (either always or when in use) you can then use `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` and `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]` to control whether location updates are delivered to your delegate.

So, the short answer is call `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]` after 30 minutes.

Comment: Yes, it works but in the app settings under privacy -> location services- > then there is 3 options: 1)never 2) While using the app 3)Always and even the app not running in the background (after i add [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] and  [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; then the third option is selected still 3)Always  I want that the setting will change to "While using the app" ...

Comment: You can't request a lower level of authorisation once authorization is granted. Once you have been granted "always" authorization that is what you have.  Your app may not always use location, but it is authorized to do so.